# PHP Zip Archive organized in a Array

Tags: php, zip, archive

I am trying to organize a Zip Archive into an array so that I may extract certain files into their rightful place.

The Zip contains 3 folder, and in each folder holds files that may be extracted depending on their extension.

Zip
-> Folder 1

-----File 1

-----File 2

-----File 3

-> Folder 2

-----File 1

-----File 2

-> Folder 3

-----File 1

-----File 2

At the moments, the folder are named numerically.

Folder 1

Folder 1.1

Folder 2

However, when I put them in a loop to describe the statIndex to an array, the folder are rearrange as follow in the array:

array[0] = Folder 1

array[1] = Folder 2

array[2] = Folder 1.1

I am trying to sort the statIndex so that Folder 1.1 would come after Folder 1, then after Folder 1.1, Folder 2 would come.

The Key of the array are important for organizing the data, and thus why I need help sorting statIndex. Thus:

array[0] = Folder 1

array[1] = Folder 1.1

array[2] = Folder 2

Help is very appreciated.

My Code: http://pastebin.com/6VRvWPqr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use natsort to sort the array how you want it.

```
<?php

$values = array('Folder 1', 'Folder 2', 'Folder 1.1');

// Unordered.
print_r($values);

// Sort the values.
natsort($values);

// Ordered
print_r($values);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Folder 1
    [1] => Folder 2
    [2] => Folder 1.1
)
Array
(
    [0] => Folder 1
    [2] => Folder 1.1
    [1] => Folder 2
)
```